# How does OGR detect what GEOS version I have?

Tags: ogr, geos

I'm attempting to solve this error:

```
ERROR 6: GEOS 3.8 or later needed for MakeValid.
```

The version of GDAL I am running is 3.0.4 which was downloaded as a .whl from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

The version of GEOS that ships with this .whl is unknown so I assume it's <3.8.

To that end I have downloaded GEOS 3.8.0 separately and managed to compile it sucessfully and generate the geos_c.dll and geos.dll to replace the ones in my current python installation.

The only issue is that the error remains still remains when trying to run the code.

Comment: Perhaps you must compile also GDAL again and point is to use the newer GEOS.

Comment: You may look at the question "How to check for DLL dependency?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency to track dll dependencies. It may help understand the issue and maybe fix it.

Comment: I've got the same issue on Windows with Gdal 3.0.4 from http://www.gisinternals.com/ build with geos-3.4 and a homebrew Python3.
I've tried to replace geos.dll ans geos_c.dll with the binaries from http://download.osgeo.org in 3.8.1-1 but I still have the same exception warning.
It's not a depedencie problem because the geos.dll are found.
I suppose that there is the geos version somewhere but I can't figure where.